# How to properly write boolean or logic in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, boolean-logic, booleanquery

I want to grab all documents with `loId=6` **AND** `(actionType = "SAVE_DATA"` **OR** `actionType = "OPEN_SCREEN")`.

**Am I writing this logic incorrectly?**

**Why does my query return 0 results?**

**Note**: I'd accept a query or a filter to resolve this issue.

These are some sample documents:

```
 {
    "_index": "logs",
    "_type": "record",
    "_id": "eIIt3vtrSxmdOVGClQmN3w",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
       "timestamp": 1373569919000,
       "uid": 6,
       "paId": 56298,
       "loId": 6,
       "prId": 2,
       "vId": 6577,
       "actionType": "SAVE_DATA"
    }
 },
 {
    "_index": "logs",
    "_type": "record",
    "_id": "yQGCia6qRYCImZLyH7DrEA",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
       "timestamp": 1373570314000,
       "uid": 6,
       "paId": 56641,
       "loId": 6,
       "prId": 2,
       "vId": 6578,
       "actionType": "CHECK_IN"
    }
 },
 {
    "_index": "logs",
    "_type": "record",
    "_id": "2raajrNKTKeRKG88wiNPpw",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
       "timestamp": 1373570532000,
       "uid": 6,
       "paId": 56641,
       "loId": 6,
       "prId": 2,
       "vId": 6579,
       "actionType": "LOAD_DATA"
    }
 },
 {
    "_index": "logs",
    "_type": "record",
    "_id": "0FDBxW2ESl6tfmj81YJvIg",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
       "timestamp": 1373570761000,
       "uid": 6,
       "paId": 56298,
       "loId": 6,
       "prId": 2,
       "vId": 6577,
       "actionType": "OPEN_SCREEN"
    }
 },
 {
    "_index": "logs",
    "_type": "record",
    "_id": "-bFQyEdCQVWiXNldtxz04g",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
       "timestamp": 1373570777000,
       "uid": 6,
       "paId": 56298,
       "loId": 6,
       "prId": 2,
       "vId": 6577,
       "actionType": "OPEN_SCREEN"
    }
 }
```

**Query**

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
          "query": {
              "term": {
                    "loId": 6
              }
          }, 
         "filter": {
            "or": {
               "filters": [
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "actionType": "SAVE_DATA"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "actionType": "OPEN_SCREEN"
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "_cache": false
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main reason you're having trouble getting results is because you're trying to do a `term` filter on `actionType`, which is an analyzed field. If you want to do `term` matching on that field, you'll need to update your type mapping to set that field to `not_analyzed`. See this example mapping:

```
{
   "record": {
      "properties": {
         "actionType": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
         },
         "loId": {
            "type": "long"
         },
         "paId": {
            "type": "long"
         },
         "prId": {
            "type": "long"
         },
         "timestamp": {
            "type": "long"
         },
         "uid": {
            "type": "long"
         },
         "vId": {
            "type": "long"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Read up on mappings starting here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/. You'll need to reindex your data. With that fixed, here's a query that will work:

```
{ 
    "query": { 
        "filtered": {
           "query": {"match_all":{}},
           "filter": {
               "bool": {
                   "must": [
                       {"term": {"loId":6}},
                       {
                           "or": [
                               {"term":{"actionType": "SAVE_DATA"}},
                               {"term":{"actionType": "OPEN_SCREEN"}}
                           ]
                       }
                   ]
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, James. That was exactly the issue. I guess I missed that bit when I read the documentation.